# UPDATE the records in oracle SQL with joinings and where exists query

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have the tables below and

1. tempaddresstable
2. account
3. premise
4. address

Here is the link of details(id of account = account_fk of premise)
(address_fk of premise = id of address)

So only goal is to update all the records  info from tempaddresstable to address table

I have tried the below query but I am getting error

```
UPDATE ADDRESS AD
SET AD.ADDRESS1 =
  (SELECT (B.TEMPADDRESS1)
   FROM tempAddressTable B,
        ADDRESS AD
   WHERE AD.ID =
       (SELECT (P.ADDRESS_FK)
        FROM ACCOUNT A
        LEFT JOIN tempAddressTable B ON A.EXT_REF = B.TEMPEXTREF
        LEFT JOIN PREMISE P ON A.ID = P.ACCOUNT_FK
        LEFT JOIN ADDRESS AD ON AD.ID = P.ADDRESS_FK
        WHERE A.EXT_REF = B.TEMPEXTREF ))
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT 1
     FROM tempAddressTable B
     WHERE AD.ID =
         (SELECT DISTINCT max(P.ADDRESS_FK)
          FROM ACCOUNT A
          LEFT JOIN PREMISE P ON A.ID = P.ACCOUNT_FK
          LEFT JOIN tempAddressTable B ON A.EXT_REF = B.TEMPEXTREF
          WHERE A.EXT_REF = B.TEMPEXTREF ));
```

Error :

**SQL Error: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"
*Cause:

*Action:**

**Details of the table**

1. tempaddresstable
2. account
3. premise
4. address

**tempaddresstable**

```
+------------+----------------------------+
| TEMPEXTREF | TEMPADDRESS1               |
+------------+----------------------------+
| 34         | 101 DRCSG117432RES RD TEST |
| 35         | 102 DRCSG117               |
| 36         | 100 DRCSG117432RES RD      |
+------------+----------------------------+
```

**account**

```
+---------+---------+
| ID      | EXT_REF |
+---------+---------+
| 1041261 | 34      |
| 1041262 | 35      |
| 1041263 | 36      |
+---------+---------+
```

**premise**

```
+---------+------------+------------+
| ID      | ACCOUNT_FK | ADDRESS_FK |
+---------+------------+------------+
| 1044610 | 1041261    | 1041502    |
| 1044611 | 1041262    | 1041503    |
| 1044612 | 1041263    | 1041504    |
+---------+------------+------------+
```

**address**

```
+---------+----------+
| ID      | ADDRESS1 |
+---------+----------+
| 1041502 | test     |
| 1041503 | test     |
| 1041504 | test     |
+---------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it not do the job for you ?

```
drop table tempaddresstable;
create table tempaddresstable (tempextref number, tempaddress1 varchar2(100));
insert into tempaddresstable values (34, '101 DRCSG117432RES RD TEST');
insert into tempaddresstable values (35, '102 DRCSG117');
insert into tempaddresstable values (36, '100 DRCSG117432RES RD');
commit;

drop table accounts;
create table accounts (id number, ext_ref number);
insert into accounts values (1041261 , 34);
insert into accounts values (1041262 , 35);
insert into accounts values (1041263 , 36);
commit;

drop table premise;
create table premise (id number, account_fk number, address_fk number);
insert into premise values (1044610 ,1041261 ,1041502);
insert into premise values (1044611 ,1041262, 1041503);
insert into premise values (1044612 ,1041263, 1041504);
commit;

drop table address;
create table address (id number, address1 varchar2(100));
insert into address values (1041502, 'test');
insert into address values (1041503, 'test');
insert into address values (1041504, 'test');
commit;


update address a set a.address1 = 
(
with results as 
(select p.address_fk,t.tempaddress1
from accounts aa join tempaddresstable t on aa.ext_ref = t.tempextref join 
premise p on p.account_fk = aa.id  )
select tempaddress1 from results r
where r.address_fk = a.id);

commit;
```

> I have committed more mistakes than have fixed them so please test any and all of my solutions before you implement them in production. Best Regards, Adnan.